# Laravel 4.2 : Route (get) not work after another route (match)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I'm on Laravel 4.2 and I have a route (get) that does not work after another route (match).

She works before but not after.

**The following code does not work**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'messages'), function(){
    ...
    Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/{id}', ['uses' => 'TestController@conversation', 'as' => 'test.messagerie.conversation']);
    Route::get('x', ['uses' => 'TestController@test']);
});
```

**The following code works**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'messages'), function(){
    ...
    Route::get('x', ['uses' => 'TestController@test']);
    Route::match(['GET','POST'], '/{id}', ['uses' => 'TestController@conversation', 'as' => 'test.messagerie.conversation']);
});
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

May be in the first code

/{id} this root is prioritized then /x

so if you go to /x route this is considere as the id variable of the next **/{id} route**

If you declare in the second way you are at first declaring the route x so its prioritarized and being caught there with working finely.

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified a pattern for {id} so it's capturing everything and never reaching the 2nd route.